# How do I fix a NameError in Python?

Tags: python

This is the code that doesnt work. It keeps giving me a name error on Visual Studio code.

```
import time
import psutil

def display_usage(cpu_usage, mem_usage, bars=50):
    cpu_percent = (cpu_usage / 100.0)
    cpu_bar = '$' * int(cpu_percent*bars) + '-' * (bars - int(cpu_percent * bars))
    
    mem_percent = (mem_usage / 100.0)
    mem_bar= '$' * int(mem_percent * bars) + '-' * (bars - int(mem_percent * bars))

print(f"\rCPU Usage: |{cpu_bar}| {cpu_usage:.2f}%  ", end="")
print(f"MEM Usage: |{mem_bar}| {mem_usage:.2f}%  ", end="\r")

while True:
    display_usage(psutil.cpu_percent(),psutil.virtual_memory().percent,30)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am working with a MacBook M2 on Visual Studio Code using Python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: the print statements should be inside the display_usage(), else, `cpu_bar` variable won't be accessible.

Comment: How exactly is the [tag:security] tag related to this question as asked?

Comment: @esqew I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function defines some local variables:

```
def display_usage(cpu_usage, mem_usage, bars=50):
    cpu_percent = (cpu_usage / 100.0)
    cpu_bar = '$' * int(cpu_percent*bars) + '-' * (bars - int(cpu_percent * bars))
    
    mem_percent = (mem_usage / 100.0)
    mem_bar= '$' * int(mem_percent * bars) + '-' * (bars - int(mem_percent * bars))
```

.. but then you try to print those variables **outside** of the function, where they don't exist:

```
print(f"\rCPU Usage: |{cpu_bar}| {cpu_usage:.2f}%  ", end="")
print(f"MEM Usage: |{mem_bar}| {mem_usage:.2f}%  ", end="\r")
```

Because those lines of code are not indented, they are not treated as part of the function.

Did you mean to indent them, so they are included as part of the function?